# Man falls through time in giant worms that connect past and future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Looking for a fiction story, probably YA, about a man who fell through time down the time worms in the story. It almost killed him, and he slowly kills himself with vicious alcohol of sorts that allows him to actually experience the memories of his beloved family. At the behest of a princess-like figure, he gets sent back wrapped in material that will help him survive the trip. I'm hoping I didn't dream it up. It's a little weird; even for me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is an interesting question, but it could use a few more details.  Check out the [suggestions for a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any more details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, what year (approximately) did you read this?

Comment: What do you mean by "worms"?  Wormholes, perhaps?

Comment: "What do you mean by "worms"?"

I mean worms; giant worms described in the story that characters are prone to falling through like they get swallowed. They arrive horribly wounded and mangled. They are so badly injured that they barely survive. I don't remember much, and it took a lot to lock in on these details. The main character is in a bar drinking said alcohol that is slowly killing him because he can see his family when he does. His friend introduced him to it not knowing that he would slowly kill himself with it. A 'princess' comes to him with an offer to go back. It's not much.

Comment: However, I can tell you that those details are at the beginning of the book. I discovered it too soon and got bored with it. So, I don't know much. I know that someone tries to intervene on his drinking with the promise to make him happy, and he gets angry saying there is only one way for him to be happy and orders them to fetch it. I know that the princess figure is on a mission and is supposed to go back with him. I can't remember the names of any characters or any other details. It's vague.

Comment: *Prince of Time* by Glenna McReynolds has some similar details, specifically the "time worms"